# Do we flag duplicate answers across different questions?

Tags: support, flagging, exact-duplicates

- [Original answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42608/stripping-specific-tags-from-a-input-format-inverse-limit-allowed-html-tags-f#answer-42612)
- [Duplicate answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44046/can-i-blacklist-certain-html-tags-rather-than-whitelist-them) (different question)

The second is obviously a straight copy of the first; the second question will probably be closed as a duplicate, but what about the duplicate answer? Does that stay or go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags should be used when there is an immediate (or a potentially immediate) action that needs to be done from a moderator on a post:

- When an answer is flagged as not an answer, it needs to be deleted because it is possibly a comment, or a different question
- When a post is flagged as spam, it needs to be deleted (if it is just spam, and not also a tentative to answer the question), and the author of that post could need to be suspended/deleted

In this case, the immediate action would be voting to close one of the questions (if they are duplicates), and add the necessary attribution, which means (in the specific case) adding the following text (or similar text):

> As [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) said in [his answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42612/199) for a different question, […]

None of those actions require a moderator.

If a user would keep copying the answers given from other users, it is probably better to open a question on this very meta site.
The actions that could be taken in this case depends from how the user re-acts after s/he is said what s/he should be (not) doing, or s/he is supposed (not) to do; a question on the meta site serves as note for something that needs to be kept under observation.

Comment: Cool thanks, just wanted to check before I started filling up your flag inbox